# Limiting number of CPU cores used for indexing

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to limit how many CPU cores Xcode can use to index code in the background?

I write code in emacs but I run my app from Xcode, because the debugger is pretty great. The problem is that in emacs I use rtags for indexing, which already needs a lot of CPU, and then Xcode wants to do the same. Basically whenever I touch a common header file, my computer is in big trouble...

Answer (score 0):

I like this question, it presents hacky problem-solving :)

Not sure if this would work (not sure how to force Xcode to index) but here are some thoughts that might set you on the right track: there's a tool called [`cpulimit`](https://brewformulas.org/Cpulimit) that you can use to slow down processes (it inserts a `sleep` or something into a given process, I used it when experimenting with mining crypto).

If you can figure out the process ID of the indexing daemon, maybe you can `cpulimit` it!

I'd start by running `ps -A | grep -i xcode` before and after indexing occurs to see what's changed (if anything), or using Activity Monitor to see what spikes (`/Applications/Xcode10.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTSourceControl.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.WorkingCopyScanner.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.WorkingCopyScanner` looks interesting)

Comment: Unfortunately Xcode is spawning multiple clang processes to index stuff, so I'm afraid cpulimit doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a -i or --include-children param on cpulimit that should take care of this, but not sure how well it works in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I made a script /usr/local/bin/xthrottle;

```
#!/bin/ksh
PID=$(pgrep -f Xcode | head -n 1)
sudo renice 10 $PID
```

You can play with the nice level, -20 is least nice, 20 is nicest for your neighbour processes.